Higher-Dimensional Chain Rule for multivariate $C^k$ functions with Arbitrary Codomain Dimension
I have a question regarding the higher-dimensional chain rule. Let $U \subseteq \mathbb{R}^d$ and $V \subseteq \mathbb{R}^s$ be open sets, and suppose we are given functions $f \colon U \to V$ and $g \colon V \to \mathbb{R}^l$ and assume that $f$ and $g$ are both of class $C^k$, where $k \geq 1$ and $C^k$ stands for the set of functions with continuous $k$-th derivatives.
For the case $l = 1$, I found a higher-order chain rule formula for the composition $g \circ f$ in this paper. However, I am interested in the case where the codomain $l \in \mathbb{N}$ is arbitrary.
Examining the proof in the mentioned paper, it seems that the generalization to
$l > 1$ should follow by a similar reasoning, without even a change in the combinatorics of the higher chain formula (point 6. of the mentioned paper), but I am unclear on how the higher-order derivatives interact in this multidimensional context and how to formalize the result.
I would be really thankful for anyone providing an explicit higher-order chain rule formula for the general case or pointing me toward a reference where this generalization is discussed!

Since $g:V\to \mathbb R^\ell$, we can write $g$ as $g(v)=(g_1(v),\dots,g_\ell(v))$ for each $v\in V$, where $g_1,\dots,g_\ell$ are each functions $V\to \mathbb R$. For each $i\in \{1,\dots,\ell\}$, you can use the chain rule in that paper to compute the derivative $(g_i\circ f)'$. Finally, the derivative of $g\circ f$ is simply the vector function whose $i^\text{th}$ component is $(g_i\circ f)'$, for each $i\in \{1,\dots,\ell\}$. So, the $\ell=1$ case immediately generalizes to case for general $\ell$.

Oh, that was exactly the argument I was missing! It also makes sense now why the paper  is written for the case $l = 1$. Thank you so much for the quick and instructive answer!
